# Node.js executable file doesn't include my front end tech

Tags: javascript, node.js, executable, ejs

I have made an application in Node.js and then I have made it in executable file, but the executable file only includes the Node.js file, but it gives error That your ejs file is not found.

> Error: Cannot find module 'ejs'
>
> 1) If you want to compile the package/file into executable, please pay attention to compilation warnings and specify a literal in 'require' call.

I am making it executable with the command line

```
pkg -t node6-win entry.js
```

Can someone help me out?
I can even share zip file.

```
     {
  "name": "project_along_voice-mongo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Chatbot",
  "main": "server.js",
  "bin": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build=package":"pkg package.json",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "chatbot"
  ],
  "assets" : ["plugins/*"],
  "author": "wurth",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "ejs": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mitsobox": "0.1.4",
    "mongo": "^0.1.0",
    "mongod": "^2.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3"
  },
  "pkg": {
    "assets" : [
      "views/*",
      "public/*"
       ],
       "target" : [ "node8"]
   }
}
```

Folder Structure

[image: folder Structure]

Answer (score 1):

The node modules need to be bundled in the executable here.
You need to add scripts and assets in the package.json file and use the option to build through package.json.

```
"pkg": {
"scripts": "node_modules/**/*.js",
"assets": "views/**/*"
}
```

Comment: its not working that way.. i have tried that. See above i have edited the package.json above

Comment: Can you share your folder structure?

Comment: added it too above

Comment: Ok. I don't know what steps have you followed to get to this. So I'm going to list all the steps.
1. add `#!/usr/bin/env node` to the server.js on top
2. add `"bin": {
    "packIt": "./server.js"
  }` to package.json
3. add `"pkg": {
"assets": ["views/**/*", "node_modules/**/*"]
}` to package.json
4.add `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '.','views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` to server.js
5.In your root directory run `pkg package.json`
Please ensure you have taken all these steps.

Comment: @DEVCNN I was able to run as per your detailed instructions. Thanks.